# Swift: UIImageView not loading on physical iphone

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I am trying to load an image into a UIImageView, I am using SDWebImage.
The picture is stored in my localhost as a url and I've allowed HTTP requests in my project.

The image loads successfully into my Simulator in XCode but when use my physical iPhone it doesn't want to load.

Any solutions?

Comment: This is might be obvious, but are you sure that your physical device is connected to internet?

Comment: If you go in safari to that URL, the image appears?

Comment: What do you mean by "localhost"? When running in the simulator, the localhost is your Mac. When running on an iPhone, the localhost is the iPhone. The last thing you should be using in an iOS app is "localhost".

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using MAMP (Apache & MySQL Server), so I read the URL out of my database as a string (http://localhost:8888/images/AsusK541UA.png for example). And to connect to the database I replace the 'localhost' with the IP address of my router so I can access the data from my iPhone because the database is hosted on my MacBook (iPhone and MacBook are on the same network)
(http://192.168.2.4:8888/images/AsusK541UA.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your application in the Simulator... you're actually running a Mac OS X application and it has full access to the suite of Mac OS X software.  Most notably it has access to a lot more image loaders, lots more file formats, than you may have on your phone.

What format is your image in?  It may be in a format that is recognized by Mac OS X and not iOS.

Comment: My picture has the .png extension so I think this is not the issue?

Comment: That's not necessarily the case.  There are some .png images that the phone cannot draw.